# Akka - Declaring an implicit exception handler

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-http

I created my custom exception handler and I want it to work as implicit object but despite throwing an exception in my actor it is not being invoked. I'm getting a status OK from API while I should be getting Bad Request for a invalid model.

ExceptionHandler:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpResponse
import akka.http.scaladsl.server._
import Directives._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.StatusCodes._
import regularmikey.credentials.exception.ValidationException

class CustomExceptionHandler {
  implicit def customExceptionHandler(): ExceptionHandler =
    ExceptionHandler {
      case _: ValidationException =>
        extractUri { uri =>
          println(s"Request to $uri could not be handled normally")
          complete(HttpResponse(BadRequest, entity = "There was a problem with validation"))
        }
    }
}

object CustomExceptionHandler extends CustomExceptionHandler
```

API trait

```
import akka.actor.{ActorRef, Status}
import akka.actor.Status.Status
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.StatusCodes._
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.{ExceptionHandler, Route}
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.util.Timeout
import regularmikey.credentials.dto.RegisterRequest
import regularmikey.credentials.dto.RequestMarshaller._
import regularmikey.exception.CustomExceptionHandler

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContextExecutor, Future}

trait CredentialsApi {
  def createCredentialsActor(): ActorRef

  implicit def requestTimeout: Timeout
  implicit def executionContext: ExecutionContextExecutor

  implicit def exceptionHandler: ExceptionHandler = CustomExceptionHandler.customExceptionHandler()
  lazy val credentialsActor: ActorRef = createCredentialsActor()

  val credentialsRoute: Route =
    path("register") {
      post {
        pathEndOrSingleSlash {
          entity(as[RegisterRequest]) {
            request => {
              complete {
                val response: Future[Status] =
                  (credentialsActor ? request).mapTo[Status]
                OK
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Actor:

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorLogging, Props, Status}
import akka.util.Timeout
import cats.data.Validated
import regularmikey.credentials.dto.RegisterRequest
import regularmikey.credentials.dto.validation.RegisterRequestValidatorNec
import regularmikey.credentials.exception.ValidationException

import scala.concurrent.Future

object CredentialsActor {
  def props(implicit timeout: Timeout) = Props(new CredentialsActor)
}

class CredentialsActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  def receive: Receive = {
    case RegisterRequest(userName, password, passwordRepeated) =>
      val result = RegisterRequestValidatorNec.validateRegisterRequest(userName, password, passwordRepeated)
      result match {
        case Validated.Valid(a) => sender() ! Status.Success
        case Validated.Invalid(e) => sender() ! Status.Failure(new ValidationException(e.toString))
      }
  }
}

class ValidationException(message: String) extends Exception
```

Comment: Can you add more logs or breakpoints? Specially on line `case Validated.Invalid`? I think problem in this line: you don't throw exception, but simple send it. [Doc](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/exception-handling.html)

Comment: Also you don't use response val: `val response: Future[Status] = (credentialsActor ? request).mapTo[Status]; OK`

Answer (score 0):

The `ExceptionHandler` is picked up implicitly by the `route2HandlerFlow` which is what turns a `Route` to a `Flow[Request, Response, _]`. This means that if you want to provide it implicitly it needs to be available where that conversion happens, most often where you call `bindAndHandle` and pass your `Route` to it, which triggers the conversion.

If you rather want to do it as a part of the `Route` definition you can wrap it with the explicit `handleExceptions` directive (docs: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/execution-directives/handleExceptions.html )

Comment: Can you elaborate on declaring exception handler in a place when I call 'bindAndHandle'? Currently I've done something like this

protected implicit def exceptionHandler: CustomExceptionHandler = CustomExceptionHandler

In my Main object but still with no result. After throwing exception I still have a Ok response

Comment: It needs to be in scope where you call bind, as that is where it is used, so that _should_ be enough. If you are using IntelliJ it can be helpful to toggle View > Show implicit hints. This is the sample for an implicit handler from the docs: https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/v10.1.11/docs/src/test/scala/docs/http/scaladsl/server/ExceptionHandlerExamplesSpec.scala#L52-L80 in case that helps figuring it out.

Comment: In newer versions of akka-http (>=10.2.0) `route2HandlerFlow` is deprecated and `route2Flow` doesn't take implicit handlers. Looks like the docs need some cleaning.